# How are symbols resolved when creating a dynamic library?

Tags: c, linker

For example, let's say I have the following structure:

`my_program
| main.c - defines main()
| foo.c - defined foo()
my_dll
| dll_start.c - defined dll_start()
| foo.c - defines foo()`

where main() calls foo() and then dll_start().

In what order are they called? For example, is it:

1. my_program::main
2. my_program::foo
3. my_dll::dll_start
4. my_dll::foo

?

Basically, I want to know if when you create a dynamic library, if the linker (does the linker even run?) always uses symbols inside the dll when resolving symbols inside the dll itself - for example, in this case, does the foo() inside my_dll call the my_dll::foo or the my_program::foo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the linker runs to finalize the build of the DLL and will need a definition of `foo` to build.  But as long as you aren't linking the same library of code containing `my_program::foo` into `my_dll.dll`, the `foo` picked up for linking the DLL itself will be `my_dll::foo`.

The only time you can get yourself in trouble here is if you had a `shared.lib` static code library that implements an independent `foo` function and is linked with both with the EXE and DLL. It might be ambiguous which one the DLL picks up if it has a local implementation of `foo`.

Comment: Ah okay, I wasn't sure if the linker ran and resolved references for DLLs. Not sure where I could've found this info though... I can't really find anything.

Comment: Ordered. Thanks.